# Extract the photo with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image like the one below, and I want to responsively bring out half of it. position: absolute; When I use it, the photo stays steady when the screen shrinks. How can I do it?

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

```css
.macbook_bg{
    width: 50rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: -145px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="project-description">
         <h2>Our Solution</h2>
         <h3>Woody Chair has the guts to design and develop the impossible. With passion and a lot of
            expertise we create a surprisingly timeless collection of beautiful functional furniture,
            made with innovative and sustainable materials. Our brand represents connection.
         </h3>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="macbook_bg" src="assets/images/mac.png" alt="images">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning takes it out of the flow until it has a relative parent.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap and that's why I can't use the column structure. Photograph and text intertwine. The photo size remains the same. My css knowledge is weak, I have no information about how to do it. @m4n0

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a background image.

HTML:

```
  <div class="backgroundImage"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.backgroundImage
  width 50vw
  height 500px
  background url("../img/background.jpg")
  background-size auto 100%
  background-repeat no-repeat
  background-position left
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something along these line:

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 image-div">
  <img class="macbook_bg" src="assets/images/mac.png" alt="images">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.image-div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: -145px;
}

.macbook_bg{
    width: 200%;
    position: relative;
}
```

- Using a div with `overflow: hidden` allows you to limit how much of the image you want to see. `width: 200%` makes the image twice as big, thus showing only half of the image.
- Using percentages for width and height instead of `rem` allows you to keep the image size relative to the screen size.